# Consulta ajax no me permite realizar más acciones

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rendimiento

Tengo un dashboard que se muestra en la pantalla principal cuando el usuario inicie sesión.

Inicialmente tengo dos gráficas, una de líneas y una de barras. El problema es que las consultas de las gráficas son un poco pesadas y se demoran aproximadamente 30 segundos en cargar.

Ya hice optimización de las consultas y se mejoraron un poco, el problema es que al querer acceder a otras opciones del menú de la página no me deja, porque me toca esperar hasta que se carguen las gráficas.

Es íncomodo al usuario esperar hasta que las gráficas carguen, quisiera saber si hay una manera de que se pueda acceder a otras opciones de la página sin importar que las gráficas esten cargando.

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
/*
* Se obtienen las urls que tiene acceso el usuario en el dashboard. Esto se                  *  ejecuta cuando el usuario este en la pantalla principal.
*/
  $.getJSON(getBaseUri() + 'dashboard/index', function(data) {

    var datas  = data['return'];

    if(datas == ""){
      $productivities.removeClass('chartID');
      $productions.removeClass('chartID');
      $combox.addClass('hidden');
    }

    for (var i in datas) {
      receiveData({
        div       : datas[i].div,
        title     : datas[i].privilege,
        sign      : datas[i].sign,
        iconClass : datas[i].class,
        id        : datas[i].id,
        label     : datas[i].label,
        xaxis     : datas[i].xaxis,
        yaxis     : datas[i].yaxis,
        background: datas[i].background,
        url       : datas[i].route,
        type      : datas[i].type
      });
    }
  });

/*
   * La función receiveData() recibe los parámetros de los dashboard que tiene acceso el usuario y trae los data de cada controlador consultado, y de acuerdo al tipo de gráfica se ejecuta la función.
   */
  function receiveData(param) {

    $.ajax({
      url: param.url,
      method: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data){
        var datas = data['return'];

        if(param.type === "LineChart"){
          lineChart({
            data : datas,
            div  : param.div,
            title: param.title,
            url  : param.url
          });
          $loaderProduction.addClass("hidden");
        }

        if (param.type === "BarChart") {
          barCharts({
            data      : datas,
            div       : param.div,
            title     : param.title,
            url       : param.url,
            label     : param.label,
            xaxis     : param.xaxis,
            yaxis     : param.yaxis,
            background: param.background
          });
          $loaderProductivity.addClass('hidden');
        }

        if (param.type === "Indicator") {
          indicatorsChart({
            data  : datas,
            div   : param.div,
            title : param.title,
            icon  : param.sign,
            class : param.iconClass,
            idDash: param.id
          });
        }

        if (param.type === "Sowing") {
          sowingIndicator({
            data  : datas,
            div   : param.div,
            title : param.title,
            idDash: param.id
          });
        }
      },
      error: function(error){
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  }
```

Basicamente estas son las funciones que estoy usando para mostrar las gráficas del dashboard.

Comment: ¿Qué opciones del sistema? No entiendo lo que no te funciona, todo parece estar en orden en el código y la ejecución de las llamadas parece asíncrona, ¿qué problema tienes exactamente?. ¿Podrías poner un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Gracias.

Comment: ¿Quieres decir que básicamente la UI se bloquea mientras realizas la petición AJAX?

Comment: Sí, cuando el usuario inicia sesión y quiere dar clic en un menú que tiene el sistema, no puede porque toca esperar hasta que las gráficas carguen, entonces lo que quiero es que se pueda acceder a las otras opciones del menú sin importar que las gráficas esten cargando @guzgarcia

Comment: Al iniciar sesión se empiezan a cargar las gráficas, pero se demoran un poco, pero si el usuario quiere acceder a otras opciones del menú del programa no deja porque toca esperar hasta que las gráficas carguen, entonces no sé si hay una manera de que las gráficas carguen por debajo @OscarGarcia

Comment: Por defecto todas las llamadas a [`$.ajax()`](`http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/`) producen una llamada asíncrona a no ser que se indique lo contrario con el parámetro `async: false` y [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) es un alias de `$.ajax()`, por lo que no debería darte problemas a no ser que hay otro problema más. ¿Podrías darme la URL o generar un ejemplo verificable como te pedí?

Comment: Voy a tratar de generar un ejemplo, porque estoy trabajando en mi localhost @OscarGarcia

Comment: Como te dicen, una petición AJAX es asíncrona por naturaleza ha no ser que indiques lo contrario, lo cual es malo. Creo que el parseo se está llevando sobre un JSON gigante. Te recomendaría evitar respuestas con grandes cantidades de datos por cuestión de rendimiento. Un cliente con un ancho de banda limitado se demoraría muchísimo en obtener una respuesta lo cual no es ideal para una buena UX.

Comment: Si las peticiones son asíncronas, sólo que estoy mirando si se pueden hacer esas peticiones en segundo plano para que no afecten otras opciones de la página, es decir, mientras se cargan las gráficas, pueda acceder a otro menú sin que me toque esperar que carguen @guzgarcia

Comment: No hay segundo plano en JavaScript, Fabian. Tu única opción es usar WebWorkers. Aún así, sigo pensando que una respuesta de ese tamaño es contraproducente. WebWorkers tiene un soporte bastante decente, échale un ojo a algún tutorial.

Comment: Vale voy a revisar y leer la documentación! @guzgarcia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta buscar información de ajax MultiThread, o lo que más se conoce como ajax asincrono y sincrono, que habla sobre varias peticiones para ajax al mismo tiempo, quizás este enlace pueda servirte de algo

https://facilphp.wordpress.com/2010/11/22/ajax-asincrono-y-sincrono/

Comment: Voy a revisar el enlace gracias :) @CarlosEstarita

Comment: Aca también te dejo otro, que al parecer pudo ayudar a otra persona que tenia tu mismo problema. pero esta en ingles: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468772/multi-threading-in-javascript

Comment: Por defecto todas las llamadas a [`$.ajax()`](`http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/`) producen una llamada asíncrona a no ser que se indique lo contrario con el parámetro `async: false` y [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) es un alias de `$.ajax()`, por lo que esa información no soluciona el problema. Aún así gracias por el esfuerzo :) PD: Único soporte de multithread para Javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: Se me pasó el tiempo de edición antes de poder agregar datos de compatibilidad. Por ahora sólo es compatible Chrome, Firefox y Opera. Ni Safari ni navegadores móviles iOS ni Android son compatibles. Es un estándar aún en desarrollo: http://caniuse.com/#feat=sharedworkers